# Creating a local variable instead of calling a method to get data

Tags: memory-efficient, coding-style

My question is about the efficient code. Please let me know which is the efficient approach among the given below.

There's a method call to get an object. For eg.,

```
relationship.getCommerceItem()
```

But, we need to call this method multiple times in a single line itself. So, I'm planning to create a local variable to replace the method call and store the return value. Like given below.

```
commerceItem = relationship.getCommerceItem()
```

Now, which approach is more efficient and why?

Considering that this code will be executed in an environment where thousands and thousands of requests will be received.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not the logic executed in the called function needs to be ran every time. In other words, does the return value change?

If not, saving it in a variable saves you the resources needed for the function call (which is the most sane thing to do IMO).

Comment: No. The return value will not change. This code "relationship.getCommerceItem()" will be executed at least  4 times for a comparision operation. So, I thought it would be more readable to extract the method call into a variable. At the same time, I had doubt about the memory space needed for the variable too. So, I posted this question.

Comment: @user6564898 In that case, saving it in a variable is the way to go. I don’t know the implementation of your getCommerceItem() method, but I’m guessing it fetches something from the database, builds an object from fetched data and returns that object. Which do you think requires more resources? Reading the object from memory 1000 times or running that function a 1000 times?

Comment: Hi, @user6564898, the object relationship will already have the required data/object loaded. It'll not make any database calls. So, now it's just a method call. Can you please suggest which one would be the good approach.